# Regarding JSON Store in worklight 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am new to worklight. In IBM information or knowledge center all the API are discussed but not about their attributes.I need to know about the list of api and its attributes and option.Please give me some link.

Comment: Can you try and be more specific?

Comment: Like the options that can be passed inside the WL.JSONStore.init(collections,options) and even inside collections

Answer (score 1):

This is explained very well in the documentation.

For example, you asked about WL.JSONStore.init, so for [JSONStore.init](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.JSONStore.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-16):

```
{string} options.username Optional - Name of the file that is created to store data for the collections, must be an alphanumeric string ([a-z, A-Z, 0-9]) and start with a letter. The default one is 'jsonstore'.
{string} options.password Optional - Password that is used to secure the contents of the store, by default there is no data encryption.
{boolean} options.clear Optional - Clears accessors without removing its contents from the store.
{boolean} options.localKeyGen Optional - Flag that determines if key generation uses a local (false) or remote (true) random number generator.
```

[Collection is not an API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_gs_javascript.html)... [read the Overview section](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_api_concepts.html).

Comment: Ok i am taking about the attributes/options like push:false and etc. i need those kind of attribute information